# How to enable or disable a button based on a value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

How to enable or disable a button according to a select value?
I want a button to be disabled but once a select value is changed to a certain vaue "xxxx" the button is enabled.

Comment: Very simple: ngModel + ngDisabled directives. Check documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ng-disabled` [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Etat</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="singleSelect"  ng-model="demande.etat">
        <option value="etude">etude</option>
        <option value="Accepte">Accepte</option>
        <option value="Refus">Refus</option>
    </select><br>
</div>
```

and in the button markup use something like this:

```
<button ng-disabled="demande.etat != 'Accepte'">
    ....
</button>
```

Comment: my angularjs doesn't recognize the ng-disabled.

Comment: @SaidiMeriem Which version of angular are you using? Btw. does the app not recognize the directive or does it not bind to your data? Please inlcude your controller & html sources in your original post so that we can see where the problem might be.

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.4.7 and yes the app is not recognizing the directive

Comment: I've edited my hint to reflect what you have in your document. 1.4.7 should work with `ng-disabled`. So the question is, is it managed by the same app/controller? You can try to simply write `true` and `false` in the `ng-disabled` directive to check if the app is actually recognizing the directive there.

Comment: the ng-disabled is working, but not the propriate way, it is disabled even when demande.etat = 'Accepte'

Comment: Then the button is most likely not in the same scope as your select... try putting a `{{ demande.etat }}` in front or behind that button. If it doesn't get updated when you change the `select`'s value, then the scope doesn't apply to whatever context you're currently in at that button.

Comment: the thing is that i have a page, containing a list of demandes and in front of each one there're  buttons, one is for adding, one for deleting.. so when i click on add, a modal shows up, when i put Accept i see in the backgroung that all buttons(which were disabled (even demande.etat!='Accept') for all demandes) become enabeld but once i submit it returns to disabled.

Comment: it's mostly of the ng-repeat hein ?

Comment: Yes, `ng-repeat` changes the scope. Either use `$parent` while in the `ng-repeat` section or use a service to keep track of it.

Comment: `$parent` is a reference to the parent scope of your current scope. It's a rather quick and dirty approach...still, you can use `ng-change="$parent.functionName()"` to call a function within the parent scope. A service would be the cleaner option though...

Answer (score 1):

Use ngDisabled for more details visit:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Use the model value of the select box to enable or disable

OR

Post you code so that can be improvised

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="genererContrat(d)" title="Contrat"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontalContrat" ng-disabled="{demande.etat == Accepte}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" ></span><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" ></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this...
if you want chage then comment..

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]).
controller("myController",function($scope){
$scope.buttonShow=false;
  $scope.checkVal=function(){
    if($scope.demande.etat == "Accepte"){
      $scope.buttonShow=true;
    }else{
      $scope.buttonShow=false;    
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp" >
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
<div class="form-group" >
 <label class="control-label"> Etat</label>
<select ng-change="checkVal()" class="form-control" name="singleSelect"  ng-model="demande.etat">
<option value="etude">etude</option>
<option value="Accepte">Accepte</option>
<option value="Refus">Refus</option>
</select><br>
  
  <button ng-show="buttonShow" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="genererContrat(d)" title="Contrat"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontalContrat"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" ></span><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" ></span>Button</button>
</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ng-if` also for conditions

```
$scope.MyButton = true;

<button ng-if="MyButton === false">
  ....
</button>
```

Comment: This will stop the button from being rendered at all.

Comment: @anierzad if you use `ng-if` at proper place it will show proper data for proper condition

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question asked by the original poster.